# Javascript form validation not running

Tags: javascript

Cant get this form to even run the javascript validation. I have tried changing onclick to onsubmit in the form but havent ever got it to run the script. Sorry if this is an obvious error but ive been searching the internet for a while now. Thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email Form Page</title>
        <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">   
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validator(){
                var firstname = document.getElementsById('fname').value;
                var lastname = document.getElementsById('lname').value;
                var email = document.getElementsById('email').value;
                var subject = document.getElementsById('subject').value;
                var message = document.getElementsById('message').value;
                var errors = "";
                regex1 = /^[a-z]+$/;
                regex2 = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
                // Checks to see if all fields have been filled in
                if (firstname == ""){
                    errors += 'First name field is empty \n';
                   }
                if (lastname == ""){
                    errors += 'Last name field is empty \n';
                   }    
                if (email == ""){
                    errors += 'Your Email field is empty \n';
                   } 
                if (subject == ""){
                    errors += 'Subject field is empty \n';
                   }                    
                if (message == ""){
                    errors += 'Message field is empty \n';
                   }
                // Checks if first name contains only letters     
                if (regex1.text(firstname)) == false {
                    errors += 'First name can not contain numbers \n';
                }
                // Checks if last name contains only leters 
                if (regex1.text(lastname)) == false {
                    errors += 'Last name can not contain numbers \n';
                }   
                // checks to see if email is valid
                if (regex2.text(email) == true) {
                    errors += 'Email was not valid \n';
                }

                //alerts errors and kills form
                if (errors != ""){
                    alert(errors);
                    return false;
                }

        </script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> Send me an Email </h1>
        <div class= "container">
        <form name="emailform" method="post">
            First Name: <input type='text' name ='firstname' id="fname"> <br>
            Last Name:  <input type='text' name ='lastname' id="lname"> <br>
            Your Email: <input type='text' name ='email' id ="email"> <br>
            Subject:    <input type='text' name='subject' id ="subject">  <br>
            Message:    <textarea rows='6' cols='30' name='message' id="messsage"> </textarea> <br>
            <input type='submit' value ='Send' name='submit' onclick= "validator()">
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: check your syntax `if (regex1.text(firstname)) == false` is invalid, also there is no `.text` method on RegExp objects are you meaning `.test`. You should have gotten error messages on your browser's Developer's Tools console

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in some of your if statements.

e.g.

```
 if (regex1.text(firstname)) == false {
                    errors += 'First name can not contain numbers \n';
                }
```

Should be

```
if (regex1.text(firstname) == false) {
                    errors += 'First name can not contain numbers \n';
                }
```

Some other errors

- Using document.getElementsById - this should be getElementById as should only be one element with this id
- Message textarea has an id of 'messsage' not 'message'
- As Patrick said in his comments there should be a a test not text method.